# CodeIgniter htaccess modification for semi https and without www version

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

Rather than in core PHP, htaccess modification is different.
So, after some searching  I have reached to the following code.

before that,
my requirements are standard in my project.

- www is strictly not allowed in whole site. i.e. redirect directly to non-www version.
- HTTPS is for some pages. (checkout, login page) . Strictly HTTP for other pages.
- removing CodeIgniter's default index.php

Here is my code.

```
RewriteEngine on

#################################
# force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (checkout|login)
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# force HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(checkout|login|css|img|js)
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Strict to non-www version >>> Not Working
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI}/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [L]
```

**Issue:** Not able to reach to result of non-www version of site

---

**update(17 Oct)**

```
# Strict to non-www version.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (login|account_detail|alternate_address|update_password)
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(login|account_detail|alternate_address|update_password|https|css|img|js|resources|images)
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]

# force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (login|account_detail|alternate_address|update_password)
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# force HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(login|account_detail|alternate_address|update_password|https|css|img|js|resources|images)
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [L]
```

On this new updated code, htaccess tester site displaying everything perfectly.
But, after updating to site there are many issues.

When I open this link

```
https://example.com/login
```

It keeps looping, not stopping.
And on this link
http://www.example.com/login
it redirects to

```
https://login/login
```

Comment: Try `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]`

Comment: bro can you elaborate, where can I add this line, or should I replace with something, because the suggestion you gave I tried before but didn't work.
This is like I am missing some lines or I am missing with some ordering.

Comment: Instead of `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI}/$1 [R=301,NE,L]`

Comment: Nope. It is not removing www from link.

Comment: Where do you have you .htaccess - in some folder or in the root of the website? If in the root then the problem is somewhere else, because the rule I wrote is working. You can try it here, for example http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ Enable logging for rewrite rules and look at the logs.

Comment: Thank you for the htaccess tester link bro.
I changed the line you suggested. But when I write this link [link](http://www.example.com/login) >>> its output url becomes  [link](http://example.com/login)... it must be https

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63159/discussion-between-techcare99-and-cheery).

Comment: @TechCare99 put your `# Strict to non-www version` rule before the `# force HTTPS` as those can affect the outcome of it and change this `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI}/$1 [R=301,NE,L]` into this `RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]` and see if that works, keep in mind you're using 301 redirects so you are very likely cached from previous attempts so I suggest you to use a new clean browser to make sure of the result it produces. By new clean browser I mean if you were using Internet Explorer then test with Firefox just to confirm the rule is working.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I think it is now working. With so many tweaks & turns. @Prix

Comment: Will reply the correct answer after full testing. That htaccess tester site is awesome.

Comment: @TechCare99 keep in mind that website have lots of bugs, I've use to use it to show examples to people but due to the fact it would fail in most simple scenarios and that it doesn't support `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` which is something you're currently using and very commonly used, I moved away from it.

Comment: @Prix Thanks for notifying me about it. Will take care about it.

Comment: @TechCare99 Sorry, it was 4 in the morning and I had to sleep. It your browser will be redirected to https in a second request. If you want to make it in one redirect, with keeping the check for specific URLs, then rewriterule will be larger. Online testing tool, of course, does not know about your other rules, but, again, rule for switching to https should make second redirect after the first one.

Comment: Please check updated code (update 17 Oct) in question.

Comment: @TechCare99 Have you tested the new htaccess config in localhost with your codeigniter routing? Does that work?

Comment: @TechCare99 also, try replacing `%{HTTPS} =off/on` to `%{HTTPS} off/on`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easier to handle the no-www and toggle-protocol redirects separately. In the following example:

1. The www requests are redirected to no-www as-is (handle toggle-protocol redirect on next request)
2. The http requests for selected pages are redirected to https version
3. The https requests for other pages are redirected to http version

Note the leading `/...(/|$)` in the following examples. They ensure that complete path fragments are matched (e.g. in the third set of rules `/js/main.js` matches but `/jsmith/profile` does not).

```
RewriteEngine On

# Force NOWWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

# Force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(login|account_detail|alternate_address|update_password)(/|$)
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

# Force HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(login|account_detail|alternate_address|update_password|css|img|js)(/|$)
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

# Hijack all requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [L]
```

The following tests passed:

```
http://www.example.com/
    http://example.com/

http://www.example.com/a/b?c=3&d=4
    http://example.com/a/b?c=3&d=4

http://www.example.com/login
    http://example.com/login
        https://example.com/login

https://www.example.com/js/javascript.js
    https://example.com/js/javascript.js
        http://example.com/js/javascript.js
```

**Note**: Remember to replace 302 with 301 after testing.

Comment: Thank you so much for up to mark almost correct reply. But still I am facing the issue in 2 cases.

► `https://www.example.com` leads to the same url instead it should go to only `http://example.com`
► `https://example.com` leads to same url instead it should go to only `http://example.com` . 
in common, https case is creating issue and not redirecting.

Comment: The `Force NOWWW` rule should redirect www to no-www while `Force HTTP` rule should redirect https to http. Can you double check (i) the HTTPS website uses same htaccess file (ii) there is no browser caching issue (append random query string to URLs or empty browser cache to test).