# site with www and without www is not acting same for baseurl in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I have a site where I have added the base_url() for calling the css and js files. The base_url() is without `www`. It is working fine with `http://example.com` but not working with `http://www.example.com`. That is it is showing some issues like not taking the fonts, sessions etc. I have searched many solutions but not able to find the right one. 
 Please tell me a solution.

Comment: This answer will be useful for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23996239/codeigniter-htaccess-modification-for-semi-https-and-without-www-version#26504302

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do using .htacess redirect as @Arjar Aung provided.
I used this way at my config file

```
    if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],'www')===false)
    {
        $config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com';
    }
    else
    {
        $config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com';
    }
```

Comment: Hi Shaiful Islam.That is also a very good solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Best solution if you are in pursuit of simplicity